# Combining data from 4 tables into one column/field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to created a query in MS Access 2010 that combines data from 4 different tables in one column.

The tables are defined as below;

```
Table 1: date, country, channel, calls_in
Table 2: date, country, channel, calls_out
Table 3: date, country, channel, email
Table 4: date, country, channel, chat
```

The query should look like:

```
Query 1: Date, country, channel, contacts
```

The contacts column should combine the 4 contact types (i.e. calls_in/out, email and chat) for the appropriate date, country and channel.

All 4 tables have the same dates and countries. Channel is specific to each table.

I have been trying to get this done but can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be after this:

```
SELECT
  all_contacts.date,
  all_contacts.country,
  all_contacts.channel,
  "calls in: " & [calls_in] & ", calls out: " & [calls_out] & ", email: " & [email] & ", chat " & [chat] AS contacts
FROM
  ((((select date, country, channel from [Table 1] union
      select date, country, channel from [Table 2] union
      select date, country, channel from [Table 3] union
      select date, country, channel from [Table 4])  AS all_contacts
  LEFT JOIN [Table 1] ON (all_contacts.channel = [Table 1].channel) AND (all_contacts.country = [Table 1].country) AND (all_contacts.date = [Table 1].date))
  LEFT JOIN [Table 2] ON (all_contacts.channel = [Table 2].channel) AND (all_contacts.country = [Table 2].country) AND (all_contacts.date = [Table 2].date))
  LEFT JOIN [Table 3] ON (all_contacts.channel = [Table 3].channel) AND (all_contacts.country = [Table 3].country) AND (all_contacts.date = [Table 3].date))
  LEFT JOIN [Table 4] ON (all_contacts.channel = [Table 4].channel) AND (all_contacts.country = [Table 4].country) AND (all_contacts.date = [Table 4].date);
```

Since MS-Access doesn't support FULL OUTER JOINS, and doesn't have an aggregate function like GROUP_CONCAT, I'm left joining a UNION subquery that contains all of the dates, countries and channels with every table, and I'm then combining all the contacts (calls_in, calls_out, email and chat) into one cell.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT date, country, channel, 'calls_in' AS ContactType, calls_in AS ContactData
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT date, country, channel, 'calls_out', calls_out        
FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT date, country, channel, 'email', email
FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT date, country, channel, 'chat', chat
FROM table4;
```

This will give you all the data from the four tables, with a new columns `ContactType` of the three types `calls_in`, `calls_out`, `email` and `chat` combined together with the their data.

Comment: You could improve that with a field for contact type and by renaming the contact type column so it does not end up as `calls_in`

Comment: I was thinking of `SELECT date, country, channel, "Call-in" As Contacts, calls_in AS ContactData`

Comment: @Remou Updated, thanks again. This should be your answer. BTW, is `"call-in"` is a valid literal value this way in access? shouldn't it be an identifier rather than a literal value? I write it `'calls_in'` is this OK?

Comment: Yes, it is -- SELECT "abc" as atext, 1 as anumber, Date() as adate ...`. You might get away with single quotes, double are more common.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to slightly improve of Mahmoud's answer:

```
SELECT date, country, channel, calls_in, 'Calls_in' as ContactType  FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT date, country, channel, calls_out, 'Calls_out' as ContactType FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT date, country, channel, email, 'email' as ContactType FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT date, country, channel, chat, 'Calls_in' as ContactType FROM table4;
```

But I must say that it is obvious that the database can do with some normalization. If you *can* modify the database, you can quite easily put all the data in one table and simply have a field which tracks what communication type you used.